# Doubly Linked List Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to work on a remove function for a doubly linked list, but I keep getting a Null Pointer exception on the `current.prev.next = current.next;` part. I don't think I really understand what a null pointer exception is, because I have no idea what to do to fix this. The log function is just one I wrote to write to an output file, and retval[1] is the element I'm searching to delete.

```
Node current = head;

    while(current != null)
    {
            if((current.data).compareTo(retval[1]) == 0)
            {
                    if(current.prev == null)
                        head = current.next;

                    if(current.next == null)
                        tail = current.prev;

                    current.prev.next = current.next;
                    current.next.prev = current.prev;

                    current = null;

                    valid++;
                    log(line + "\n" + "Sucsessfully Removed \n");

            }
            else
            {
                log(line + "\n" + InvalidTransaction + " - Element does not exist \n");     
            }

            current = current.next;
        }
```

I'm sure it's something stupid, but I don't know what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
current.prev.next = current.next;
current.next.prev = current.prev;
```

with

```
if(null != current.prev) current.prev.next = current.next;
if(null != current.next) current.next.prev = current.prev;
```

And also you need to break the loop once the element is found.

Answer (score 0):

A `NullPointerException` means that you tried to do something with an object that was `null`. Since `current` definitely wasn't `null`, then `current.prev` must have been `null`. Go from there.